# Nested objects issues

Tags: c#, oop

I have an object named `currHotel`. It holds values like:

- address
- bigImageUrl
- Category
- Chain
- City
- and so on

[image]

This object contains another object inside it, with different values, named - `Ben.Hotel.HotelFinder.BC_Hotel`:

[image]

How can I access the object `Ben.Hotel.HotelFinder.BC_Hotel` that's inside **currHotel**?

It doesn't appear in it, and I need some values from it:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, the values that you want to access are on your base class? In that case, check the [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) on those fields/properties/methods, and make sure that they are exposed in the way you want.

The simplest (and least safe!) approach is to make everything `public` but depending on where you are trying to read those fields/properties/methods you may be able to get away with `protected` (accessible in derived classes) or `internal` (accessible anywhere in the same assembly) instead.

**Edit:**
Also remember that there is not really a `BC_Hotel` object "inside" `current`, but rather `current` **is** a `BC_Hotel` (since its class is derived from it), so all the fields on that base class are available directly on `current`, depending on access (as I said above).

Answer (score 0):

your `currHotel` is an instance of type `Ben.Hotel.HotelFinder.BC_Hotel`.

From the screenshot, the `currHotel` doesn't have another property of type `Ben.Hotel.HotelFinder.BC_Hotel`.